# Virtual Memory Limit in IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, virtualization, memory-usage, virtual-memory

The Virtual Memory Limit(KB) setting in IIS 7 on our production server has a value 0.
Does it means our application is not using any virtual memory or does it means, there is no maximum limit on the amount of virtual memory that can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means no limit.

It just wouldn't make any sense if your application couldn't use ***any*** memory at all :-)

Comment: Thanks Massimo,
I am new to IIS management. My doubt is when Private Memory Limit(which I suppose is RAM) is also set to 0, the application would never use virtual memory unless entire RAM is filled up right?

Comment: No, "virtual memory" doesn't mean "page file"; it means "total memory allocated to the process, regardless of whether it's actually stored in physical RAM or swapped out".